# Как отображать временные данные?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp

Я создал сайт вопросов и хочу при ответе пользователя на вопросы сделать клик на варианты radio button. Выбранный вариант должен загрузиться во временную таблицу в HTML. Когда пользователь решит, что хочет завершить тест, он будет нажимать Ajax кнопку внизу таблицы, и я буду все ответы добавлять в MySQL.

У меня получается загрузить ответы при каждом клике на radio button, но когда выбираю следующий вопрос на pagionation-e, предыдущий ответ становится `null`.

Как мне решить эту проблему?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <% Logger log = Logger.getLogger("Test"); %>
        <% Long qnum = (Long) session.getAttribute("qnumer"); %>
        <% String answer = (String) session.getAttribute("answer"); %>
        <% log.info(qnum + answer); %>
        <% String[] answerqlist = new String[6]; %>
        <% switch (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(qnum))) {
            case 1:
                String a1 = answer;
                answerqlist[0] = a1;
                break;
            case 2:
                String a2 = answer;
                answerqlist[1] = a2;
                break;
            case 3:
                String a3 = answer;
                answerqlist[2] = a3;
                break;
            case 4:
                String a4 = answer;
                answerqlist[3] = a4;
                break;
            case 5:
                String a5 = answer;
                answerqlist[4] = a5;
                break;
            case 6:
                String a6 = answer;
                answerqlist[5] = a6;
                break;
        } %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border: solid 1px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                    <th>5</th>
                    <th>6</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr align="center">
                    <td><%=answerqlist[0]%></td>
                    <td><%=answerqlist[1]%></td>
                    <td><%=answerqlist[2]%></td>
                    <td><%=answerqlist[3]%></td>
                    <td><%=answerqlist[4]%></td>
                    <td><%=answerqlist[5]%></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вам сюда: https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @Regent вообще он на русском, но написан латиницей. Может у человека клавиатуры с кирилицей нет. Может даже кто то перепишет кириллицей, будет так добр.

Comment: @pavlofff мой комментарий относился к начальной редакции вопроса, а не к текущей. Заголовок, кстати, так и остался на английском.

Comment: @pavlofff надеюсь, во всём этом затяжном редактировании текста и кода будет какой-то смысл.